# Css issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hi am trying to add 2 buttons sliding with the page. I mean `position:fixed`

My website is working well on every browser except Internet Explorer.

Please take a lool to it: [Website](http://www.customizedpapers.com/)

As you see live-chat button and bookmark-us button is sliding with all browsers except Internet Eplorer.

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: What IE version are you running?

Comment: I tried it with IE7-8-9. I am trying to make it compatible with IE7-8-9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two lines of your HTML are:

```
<!--start head-tag.php-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Remove the comment above the doctype, because it's causing your site to be displayed in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

`position: fixed` does not work in IE's quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/RftZy/1/ This works.

```
.live-chat {
   position: fixed;
   height: 112px;
   width: 32px;
   z-index: 1001;
   top: 40%;
   left: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for making us go to your website to look at the code...

Internet Explorer can't render CSS like other browsers can. One thing you can count on is that sometimes the CSS has to be in the same order of the Elements in order to render correctly. Also look online for good solutions.

Comment: I am sorry for this but I couldnt get a clean css and html file. Is there any suggestion that can be the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/

might help.